# i m trying to make a form application. In this i am facing issue about if statement. find() method is of mongoose that is not the problem

Tags: reactjs, mongoose

I m trying to make a form application. In this I am facing issue about if statement. find() method is of mongoose that is not the problem

```
const user = new signupModel(req.body);
  let userRepeat = [];
  let emailRepeat = [];
  signupModel.find({ username: req.body.username }).then((result) => {
    userRepeat = result;
    console.log(userRepeat.length);
  });
  signupModel.find({ email: req.body.email }).then((result) => {
    emailRepeat = result;
    console.log(emailRepeat.length);
  });
  if (userRepeat.length === 0 && emailRepeat.length === 0) {
    user
      .save()
      .then((result) => {
        console.log(userRepeat.length, emailRepeat.length);
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log(error);
      });
  }
  res.end();
```

the above code is inside a post method and i m trying to add a user if not in database already. But it is showing something else. the length of userRepeat and emailRepeat are both greater than 0 still the if statement is executed.

Comment: the if statement runs synchronously, before the database request even finishes
you're logging only after the db request resolves, so you'd see length = 1
this code would be easier to read if you used `async/await` instead of .then

Answer (score 0):

You should take some time to learn promises properly though

```
const userRepeat = await signupModel.find(...);
const emailRepeat = await signUpModel.find(...);

if (userRepeat.length ....)
```

Try this As

The if statement runs synchronously, before the database request even finishes
youre logging only after the db request resolves, so you'd see length = 1
this code would be easier to read if you used async/await instead of .then

Comment: see, explaining the issue wasnt so complicated